# Why is a JSON response wrapped in a "_jqjsp" outer element?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I'm trying to reproduce some JSON using Spring MVC and Java. The JSON looks like this:

```
_jqjsp({
   "hits":3869,
   "highlight":{
     "include_matches":false,
     "markup_items":false
   },
   ... (lots more) ...
})
```

Which Java object type would represent the outer element `_jqjsp` and what is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Java object which represents this construct. Generate the JSON (which is a valid *subset* of JavaScript object literals) and then wrap it in the "correct" text.

See [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) as for when this form  is generated and how it is consumed:

> In the JSONP usage pattern, the URL request pointed to by the `<script>`'s src attribute returns JSON data, *with a function call wrapped around it*. In this way, a function that's already defined in the JavaScript environment can manipulate the JSON data. A JSONP payload might look like this:
>
> `functionCall({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});`

While it might not be JSONP per se, depending upon *how/where* the blocks are generated, the same rules above apply: the output represents JavaScript code that can be executed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not a JSON, but calling `_jqjsp` function with a JSON argument.

`_jqjsp` is the name of the function, and not related to JSON object.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/TipsAndTricks.md).